# Eclipse plugin reuse outside eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Is it possible to run an Eclipse Plugin outside of Eclipse?

Comment: There is a whole load of rich AST functionality in the eclipse runtime that isn't available unless you're inside Eclipse. (I'm aware that some of the AST is available outside - but not all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, because you need the Equinox runtime container.  you could run a plugin using the eclipse exeecutable, and as an application, see:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_application%3F

You're effectively creating an an `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point.

You could also publish a plugin as part of an Eclipse application and then export it as an executable so that it can be run aside from Eclipse.  This still bundles the Equinox runtime and plugin together though.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, plug-ins are still java code.  Whether or not your plug-in runs outside of Eclipse depends on what its dependencies are.  If your bundles are more OSGi oriented, you can likely run on other framework like [Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html).

If you are careful you can run outside of OSGi entirely.  For example, the Equinox Registry can run standalone outside of OSGi.  (See [this testing page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Testing_-_3.3#Extension_Registry), "Part IV. Standalone registry run")